# What is the best way to monitor disk IO for a Hyper-V Host machine?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, monitoring, hyper-v

When I fire up Perfmon on the hyper-v host, it shows only disk io for that host, and it doesn't seem to include the aggragte disk IO for all machines on the host. Is there something special I need to setup in perfmon to read total IO on the entire server? Is there another tool I should be using to take these readings?

Background: I currently have ~20 VMs on a Hyper-V host sitting on six 15k RPM local SAS drives in RAID 10. I'm looking at potentially moving to iSCSI, but I want to make sure that I'm not using more throughput than the iSCSI can provide. (I'm looking at 1 Gbps, not 10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hyper-v storage the counters to look at are:

`Physical Disk` - Physical Disk set will give overall storage performance on the system. This includes host access to the same disks (hopefully you've segregated the host from the VM storage)

```
Hyper-V Virtual Storage Device
Hyper-V Virtual IDE Controller
```

these last 2 counters are for each type of virtual stoage bus and will give you an overall level of activity on 2 bus types.  Note that you will not get latency measures as that is on the physical disk.  For your purposes I'd look at 
`Read Bytes / Sec`, `Write Bytes / Sec` on the virtual storage device